# JAXB not recognise type just puts xs:anyType in schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

How to force JAXB to recognise real type in following example as it creates xs:anyType when generates xml schema

implementation class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Response", propOrder = { "message", "companies", "resultsCount",
        "exceptionMessage" })
@XmlSeeAlso({CompanyV8.class})
public class ResponseV8 extends Response<CompanyV8>  {

}
```

parent class

```
@XmlTransient
public abstract class Response<T extends CompanyDraft>  {

    private String message;
    @XmlElement(name = "company")
    private List<T> companies;
    private Integer gisResultsCount;
    private String exceptionMessage;
```

model class

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Company",  propOrder = { "id", ...omitted... })
public class CompanyV8 extends CompanyDraft {

    @XmlElement
    private String BvDId;
    @XmlElement
    private String globalHeadquarterBvDId;
    @XmlElement
    private String parentHeadquarterBvDId;
    @XmlElement
    private String domesticHeadquarterBvDId;
    @XmlElement
    private List<BusinessPartnerSegmentDetailedV8> businessPartnerSegment;
```

xml schema

```
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="company" type="xs:anyType"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="gisResultsCount" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="exceptionMessage" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

like you can see JAXB created type="xs:anyType" instead of  type="tns:Company"

Comment: what does your XSD look like?

Comment: <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://address.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://address.com/" version="1.0"> is that what you wanted ??